# Turning a .fla into a class headache

Tags: actionscript-3, class, fla

I wrote a nice little game which works well in its .fla form. Because I wanted to include some menus with options, saves, etc, I followed the advice from http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/965/3/Better-Flash-Navigation-using-AS3-Classes/Page3.html I managed to get navigation from the menus right, but I really don't know what to do with the contents of my fla.
Ideally, I think that it should sit in a class on its own (called Game.as) which if you looked at the link above would be linked from the Main.as (which is the linked class [that navigates the menus] from the main .fla file which holds all the assets). Am I right to think that the constructor class in Game.as would be very similar to an init() function in my .fla file ? In which case, the rest of the code for the game would be separate functions (called methods for classes, right?) stored outside the constructor. Or am I completely wrong and the game should not be in class on its own but instead sitting inside the Main.as because this very class is linked to the original .fla where all the assets are? All I need is a little nudge in the right direction because I can't find this info in any of my books and I don't know how to phrase it for google. Thanks in advance. Nik

Comment: I played with my files a bit more and manage to get a mini game running from the Game.as class, where all the navigational listeners are placed in the constructor, and the game starts when the Play button is pressed, accessing one of the functions of the class, located INSIDE the class, but OUTSIDE the constructor, using PUBLIC STATIC VARs to share data with the other classes. Am I on the right path or not?

Comment: For those with the same problem, the short answer is that you cannot take your .fla, dump it in a class and hope it works. It won't. But the good thing I guess is that it makes you think about your code logic, because in this situation, sloppy code shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Export all the MovieClips and assets you want to access from classes in your FLA file. Open the properties of your MC or Bitmap and mark the export and write the package name into it.

http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/as3link/

To the rest:

Every object is another class. This is object oriented programming. Your Menu is a class, your menu items are different classes. Your game is a class, your game items are different classes and so on.

With this you can create a class hierarchy and can "load" items you need at the specific situation.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html

> Am I right to think that the constructor class in Game.as would be
>   very similar to an init() function in my .fla file ? In which case,
>   the rest of the code for the game would be separate functions (called
>   methods for classes, right?) stored outside the constructor.

Yeah, you're right.

Comment: Thanks, for this, yes, the movieclips are marked for export, and are all given a class name, and this is how they are brought to the stage with the help of the Main.as class linked to the .fla file.

Comment: edited my answer, maybe this answers more of your questions :)

Comment: Great answer, and great link thanks. I think that I understand the theory, but it becomes let's say confusing when you have to implement all these things in a real situation. I am just coming to terms with scope at the moment...